# centered anchoring in TikZ automata

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, node-connections, tikz-node

I am trying to draw an oriented regular polygon with TikZ/automata using the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=0.5pt, node distance=1.2 and 1.5, on grid,auto,>=stealth']
\def \p {10}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\pp}{\p-1}
\node[state,accepting] (0) at (2.5,0) {};

\foreach \s in {1,...,\pp}
{
  \node[state] (\s) at ({360/\p * (\s)}:\R) {};
}

\foreach \s in {1,...,\p}
{
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\ss}{\s-1}
   \path[->] (\ss) edge (\s);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

After compiling, some the arcs are not departing from the center of the corresponding node. How can I accomplish this? (I tried to add the parameter `anchor=center` to each node but the result is the same).

Comment: Could you please add to your code everything necessary from `\documentclass` to `\begin{document}` plus the `\end{document}` so it becomes a compilable minimal working example?

Comment: I found the solution in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311326/edges-on-graph-do-not-align-with-center-of-nodes-in-foreach

Comment: Should I delete the question?